# python-pip not available on Debian Bullseye

Tags: debian, software-installation, python, pip

If I try to install pip for Python 2 using `sudo apt-get install python-pip`, it throws this error message:

```
Package python-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  python3-pip
```

Is the only solution to this issue installing pip via [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py) or are there other workarounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 2 support was [dropped for Bullseye](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=938027). Downloading it directly from upstream should still work (at least, as long as Python 2 itself is available in Bullseye...).

Another solution which might work (I haven’t tried this particular scenario) is to add the Buster repositories and install `python-pip` from there. This isn’t recommended in general, but if you’re comfortable tracking testing, it shouldn’t cause any major difficulties.